# Task Completion Time

Tags: time, analytics, metrics

I am trying to measure the average time that it takes users to complete certain task in my web app.

My objective is to come up with a metric based on the time that it takes to complete each task and then take actions to reduce that time.

For instance, how long in takes for an user to register, since the click on register until the registration has been completed. This is just an example.

I have two analytics tools, Google Analytics and Pendo.

I have read many times how important is to measure Time Completion Time, but I cannot find an easy way to do it.

The closer answer to my question that I found is [here](https://uxdesign.cc/tracking-funnel-timing-in-google-analytics-e269dfbd481f).

But even then I wonder if there is something that I am missing and that can help me achieving my objective.

In Pendo I can create funnels and I can see the time that it takes on average to move to the next step, but again, I cannot get straightaway the overall time ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Measuring task completion time isn't necessarily about being very exact or precise with it (compared to things like page-loading time as a performance metric).

At the high level it is about understanding the relative amount of time your users spend entering or interacting with the interface or content compared to mulling over what to do with it.

This allows you to define a rough baseline for what is the necessary time to allow for things like input time, and also what is required for thinking time. Then it means that users who spend a lot longer for each of those baselines defined might be struggling with some aspect of the interface or content that requires more investigation.

How you measure task completion time depends on how you break down the task, and sometimes how you measure task completion is more important (or just as important) as the actual amount of time.

But you definitely don't want to get caught on the details too much and lose sight of the bigger picture here, if that's what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to answer, really appreciated.

I totally get your point and I agree with you.

As you said at the end, my goal is simple en concept but difficult technically:

I want to benchmark the average time that it takes to complete the top 10 tasks on my application, and use this metric as a goal to reduce it and also as a way to compare tasks complexity.

Actually I find out that with Pendo this can be achieved, the product doesn't offer this metric out of the box, but it offers similar Funnel feature than Google Analytics, but it gives you the time taken to the next step in your sequence.

So if you remove all those who didn't complete the funnel, you can actually calculate the time.

From what I learn until now.

**Google Analytics**, with a bit of extra code you can get user time:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings

**Pendo,** it allows you to investigate how users get to a point in your app with a feature called Paths, and then it allows you to create funnels to assess the conversion and completion time if you dig and manipulate the data.

There is no straight solution as far as I know

Thanks